# What is the `e` notation regarding to decimal numbers?

Tags: notation, real-numbers

Say the following number: $\text{1.4E-46}$.

What is the `e` meaning? I'm not talking about `euler number`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1.4E-46=1.4\times 10^{-46}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another way to express scientific notation; the numbers before E represent the front factor, and the numbers after represent the power (base 10). So, if you see $aEb=a\cdot 10^b$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $10^x$. For example $$3e-4=3\cdot 10^{-4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In this context it stands for exponentiation with base ten. It's called scientific notation.

$a E b = a \times 10^b$